# JSF RichFaces componenents on Tomcat

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am trying to run simple Richfaces component on Tomcat 7.0.5. But client side, page will be blank and the components are not getting translated. Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
    <rich:panel style="width:220px;">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Form built with inplaces"></h:outputText>
        </f:facet>
        <h:panelGrid columns="1">
            <rich:inplaceInput defaultLabel="click to enter your name" />
            <rich:inplaceSelect defaultLabel="click to choose your country" showControls="true">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="USA" itemValue="0"/>
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Canada" itemValue="0"/>
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="UK" itemValue="0"/>
            </rich:inplaceSelect>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </rich:panel>
</html>
```

This translates to blank page and the html source code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j" xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
    <rich:panel style="width:220px;">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <rich:inplaceInput defaultLabel="click to enter your name"></rich:inplaceInput>
                        <rich:inplaceSelect defaultLabel="click to choose your country" showControls="true">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></rich:inplaceSelect></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </rich:panel>
</html>
```

I have richfaces-api-3.3.3.Final.jar and richfaces-impl-3.3.3.Final.jar in lib directory.

It asked commons-logging-1.1.1.jar and so on while running. I placed all required jar file in lib directory.

What do I need to run this on Tomcat?

Comment: Where exactly is the "lib directory"?

Comment: Its under <tomCat/webapps/(projectName)/WEB-INF/lib

Comment: richfaces ui components jar might be missing

Answer (score 0):

How do you call the page? Make sure it's http://host/app/page.jsf (not .xhtml)

Comment: The HTML output shows evidence that standard JSF tags are been processed, so the URL is definitely fine.